# Why can't I trap errors that occur while calling a routine with Application.Run?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

It doesn't seem possible to trap errors when calling another routine using `Application.Run`.

```
Sub Test()
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print Application.Run("SomeRoutine", 1, 2, 3)
End Sub
```

The run-time error dialog shows up anyway.

Comment: [Here's an interesting read on how `Application.Run` works.](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/-net-office-automation/296563-catch-excel-runtime-error-winform.html)

Comment: Because the link posted by @Hao Zhang is dead, here's the [Web Archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20170513154810/http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/-net-office-automation/296563-catch-excel-runtime-error-winform.html). Also, there is another workaround that might be more appropriate than the one posted in this thread for some use cases, it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77416358/12287457).

Answer (score 1):

That's true. However, try any of the other 2 methods as a workaround:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    On Error Resume Next

    SomeRoutine 1, 1, 1
    Call SomeRoutine(2, 2, 2)

    Application.Run "SomeRoutine", 3, 3, 3

End Sub

Public Sub SomeRoutine(a, b, c)

    Debug.Print a
    Debug.Print 5 / 0

End Sub
```

With `Call` and w/o `Call` you may trap the errors neatly. With `Application.Run` - nope, because it is like an external call.

In general, you may use the *Singleton design pattern* to create the `Sub SomeRoutine` in a class. Thus, you would be able to access it through `CallByName` like this:

```
Call CallByName(objSingleTonClass, "SomeRoutine", VbMethod, 5)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. I need to call a routine using a variable string name. I would have used `CallByName` but this is in a normal module, not a class module. Guess the only way I could get around that is to build the error handling inside the called routine itself.

Comment: @HaoZhang - it would work, if you put it the function/method in a class module. This looks like a good example for a singleton design pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to determine if a routine had been called using `Application.Run`? I want to at least be able to tell.

Comment: @HaoZhang Put an optional boolean parameter in the routine and use it only when you call it via the standard calling. Thus, calling it by application run will not set it.

Comment: Hm, then I'd have to add an additional parameter to many of my functions, which is not really a viable option for me. Also, I noticed that in the call stack, there is an entry called `[<Non-Basic Code>]` where the `Application.Run` call occurs. Not sure if I can somehow access it with the default Excel security settings (programmatic access to VB project untrusted).